# FMDatabase + swift + request with undefined number of arguments

Tags: swift, fmdb

I'm trying to send a request to FMDB via a Swift class.

This is working:

```
self.database.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE id = ?", withArgumentsInArray:[anID])
```

because I used the method *executeQuery(sql, withArgumentsInArray)*

But I don't know how to use the classical method with the undefined number of arguments, instead of the one with an array:

```
self.database.executeUpdate(<#sql: String?#>, withVAList: <#CVaListPointer#>)
```

I don't know how to write my arguments in *withVAList*.

Comment: I think that Obj-C methods with a variable argument list are not converted properly (yet).

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to create an FMDatabase wrapper:

```
let success:Bool = FMDatabaseWrapper().executeUpdate(sql, food.ID?, food.name?)

func executeUpdate(sql:String, _ arguments: AnyObject?...) -> Bool
  {
    return database.executeUpdate(sql, withArgumentsInArray:arguments as NSArray)
  }
```

It works.

Comment: +1 And you can just add this method as an `extension` to `FMDatabase`, and it's seamless. You might want to not make that `AnyObject` optional, though.

Comment: And, needless to say, one can do the equivalent method for `executeQuery`, e.g.: `func executeQuery(sql:String, _ arguments: AnyObject...) -> FMResultSet? { return executeQuery(sql, withArgumentsInArray: arguments as NSArray); }` (sorry for the ugly formatting).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Swift cannot overload a same-named function with a function that takes a variable number of arguments. Thus, given a "choice" between understanding your call to `executeUpdate` as a call to `executeUpdate:withArgumentsInArray:` and a call to `executeUpdate:(NSString*)...`, the latter never comes up as a possibility.

However, there's really no problem, because you never actually need to call that method. It doesn't do anything except call `executeUpdate:withVAList:`, which you can call directly yourself, easily, by using the built-in Swift `getVaList` function (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196063/341994).

Or even better, just go right on using `executeUpdate:withArgumentsInArray:`. If there are no arguments, simply pass `nil` for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I've created an elegant SQLite library written completely in Swift called [SwiftData](https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData).

Some of its feature are:

- Bind objects conveniently to a string of SQL
- Support for transactions and savepoints
- Inline error handling
- Completely thread safe by default

It provides an easy way to execute 'changes' (e.g. INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, etc.):

```
if let err = SD.executeChange("INSERT INTO Cities (Name, Population, IsWarm, FoundedIn) VALUES ('Toronto', 2615060, 0, '1793-08-27')") {
    //there was an error during the insert, handle it here
} else {
    //no error, the row was inserted successfully
}
```

and 'queries' (e.g. SELECT):

```
let (resultSet, err) = SD.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Cities")
if err != nil {
    //there was an error during the query, handle it here
} else {
    for row in resultSet {
        if let name = row["Name"].asString() {
            println("The City name is: \(name)")
        }
        if let population = row["Population"].asInt() {
            println("The population is: \(population)")
        }
        if let isWarm = row["IsWarm"].asBool() {
            if isWarm {
                println("The city is warm")
            } else {
                println("The city is cold")
            }
        }
        if let foundedIn = row["FoundedIn"].asDate() {
            println("The city was founded in: \(foundedIn)")
        }
    }
}
```

Along with many more features!

You can check it out [here](https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData)