# How do you call an Objective-C variadic method from Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, variadic-functions

Supposing I have a class in Objective-c with a static method like this:

```
+ (NSError *)executeUpdateQuery:(NSString *)query, ...;
```

How do I call that from Swift? The autocomplete doesn't recognise it, and the compiler is unhappy with:

```
MyClassName.executeUpdateQuery("")
```

Complaining that 'MyClassName.Type does not have a member named executeUpdateQuery'

Answer (score 51):

Write a va_list version of your variadic method;

```
+ (NSError *)executeUpdateQuery:(NSString *)query, ...
{
    va_list argp;
    va_start(argp, query);
    NSError *error = [MyClassName executeUpdateQuery: query args:argp];
    va_end(argp);
    
    return error;
}

+ (NSError *)executeUpdateQuery:(NSString *)query args:(va_list)args
{
    NSLogv(query,args);
    return nil;
}
```

This can then be called from Swift

```
MyClassName.executeUpdateQuery("query %d, %d %d", args: getVaList([1,2,3,4]))
```

Add an extension to support native Swift variadic args:

```
protocol CFormatFunction {
    class func executeUpdateQuery(_ format: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> NSError?
}

extension MyClassName : CFormatFunction {
    class func executeUpdateQuery(_ format: String, _ args: CVarArg...) -> NSError?
    {
        return withVaList(args) { MyClassName.executeUpdateQuery(format, args: $0) }
    }
}

MyClassName.executeUpdateQuery("query %d %@ %.2f", 99, "Hello", 3.145)
```

Be careful, Swift doesn't provide NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION warnings (-Wformat)

```
MyClassName.executeUpdateQuery("query %@", 99)
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the Extension code you have provided but I'm getting a "Use of undeclared type 'CVarArg'" error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Replacing CVarArg with CVarArgType solved the problem. Also - why do I need the protocol?

Comment: The docs suggest to use `withVaList` instead, somewhat ominously stating that `getVaList` is "best avoided." (http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/func/getVaList/#func-getvalist_-cvarargtype)

Answer (score 8):

> `CVArgType` is useful in presenting C "varargs" APIs natively in
>   Swift. [(Swift Docs)](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/CVarArgType/)

If you have

```
+ (int)f1:(int)n, ...;
```

you first need to make a `va_list` version:

```
+ (int)f2:(int)n withArguments:(va_list)arguments
```

This can be done [without duplicating code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/695990/1016515) by calling the va_list version from the variadic version. If you didn't write the original variadic function it may not be possible (explained in [this reference](http://c-faq.com/varargs/handoff.html)).

Once you have this method, you can write this Swift wrapper:

```
func swiftF1(x: Int, _ arguments: CVarArgType...) -> Int {
     return withVaList(arguments) { YourClassName.f2(x, withArguments :$0) }
}
```

**Note** the omitted external parameter name (`_` before `arguments`), which makes the call syntax for `swiftF1` just like a normal C variadic function:

```
swiftF1(2, some, "other", arguments)
```

**Note** also that this example doesn't use `getVaList` because the [docs](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/func/getVaList/#func-getvalist_-cvarargtype) say it is "best avoided."

You can further put this function in a Swift extension of the original class, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective C

MyClassName.h

```
+ (BOOL)executeSQL:(NSString *)sql args:(va_list)args;
```

MyClassName.m

```
+ (BOOL)executeSQL:(NSString *)sql args:(va_list)arguments
{
    NSLogv(sql, arguments);

    sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:sql arguments:arguments];
    va_end(arguments);
}
```

Swift - add in its class
Works perfect

```
protocol CFormatFunction {
   class func executeSQLArg(format: String, _ args: CVarArgType...) -> Bool
}

extension MyClassName : CFormatFunction {
   class func executeSQLArg(format: String, _ args: CVarArgType...) -> Bool
   {
        return MyClassName(format, args:getVaList(args))
   }
 }
```

---

How to use

Swift

```
MyClassName.executeSQLArg(query, "one","two",3)
```

Objetive C

```
[MyClassName executeSQLArg:query, @"one",@"two",@3]
```