# How to pass CString to CVarArg?

Tags: swift, variadic-functions

**Update:** This question is no longer relevant anymore because `CString` has been removed in Xcode 6 beta 4.

---

In C, I can pass a C string (`const char *`) to a C function that takes varargs.

Now I want to do the same thing in Swift given a `CString`. I know that in Swift I cannot access C varargs functions directly, but I can access C functions that take a `va_list`, which in Swift becomes `CVaListPointer`, and I can make that with `getVaList()` from an array of `CVarArg`, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195796/).

I can successfully put integers (`Int`) and objects (`NSObject`) into the `CVarArg` array with no problem, but I can't figure out how to get a `CString` into a `CVarArg`.

Looking through the types that conform to `CVarArg` in the standard library, I see that there is a `COpaquePointer`, but I can't figure out how to get `CString` into that either.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to compile for getting a CString into a COpaquePointer :

```
var myStr : CString = "foo"
var myStrPointer:CMutablePointer<CString> = &myStr
myStrPointer.withUnsafePointer { (myPtr1 : UnsafePointer<CString>) -> () in
  let myOpaquePtr = COpaquePointer(myPtr1)
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this will work, `CString` probably already is pointer.. Maybe it would be better to get a `String` and then use `withCString { ...}` to get an `UnsafePointer<CChar>` first.

Comment: are you sure this isn't the pointer to the variable `myStr` on the stack?

Answer (score 1):

This is tested working on beta 3:

```
let myString = "abc123"
let myStringC = myString.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

myStringC.withUnsafePointerToElements {
    (myStringPtr: UnsafePointer<CChar>) -> () in
    var varargs = [COpaquePointer(myStringPtr)]
    let va_list = getVaList(varargs)
    // Use va_list...
}
```

Comment: There is no `CString` in this code. `myString` is a `String`, and `myStringC` is a `[CChar]`. Although I can get a `String` from a `CString` with `String.fromCString()`, your process of going from `String` to `UnsafePointer` is much longer than using `withCString` directly as Sulthan's comment suggests.

Comment: A C string and a C array of chars are the same thing. I tested the `withCString` method suggested by Sulthan and it didn’t work, but YMMV, I may have just messed something up when testing it.

Comment: `CString` and `[CChar]` are vastly different types in Swift. Why don't you try starting with a variable of type `CString`?