# Call variadic Objective-C function from Swift

Tags: objective-c, c, swift

I have summarized the steps of the problem, I have a C function defined in Objective-C:

ObjC.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void cuslog(NSString *format, ...);

@interface ObjC : NSObject

@end
```

ObjC.m

```
#import "ObjC.h"

@implementation ObjC

@end

void cuslog(NSString *format, ...)
{
     // Implementation
}
```

I exposed it in Bridging-Header.h:

```
#import "ObjC.h"

// Also tried to put this line in bridging header
void cuslog(NSString *format, ...);
```

In Swift I intend to call the function like this:

```
cuslog("Some log")
```

But the error says:

```
"Use of unresolved identifier 'cuslog'"
```

What is the correct way to call the function in Swift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you call an Objective-C variadic method from Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195796/how-do-you-call-an-objective-c-variadic-method-from-swift)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Swift devs, [C variadic functions are not compatible with Swift variadics](https://devforums.apple.com/message/983462#983462), so you won't be able to call your function directly.

The only workaround at this time is to write a non-variadic wrapper in C or Obj-C, and call that from Swift.

Comment: Plus, any decent API with C/Obj-C variadic functions should have a non-variadic version that takes a `va_list` argument, or a way to add elements one by one. Either of these are callable from Swift.