# How call a function objective c with args in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, call, args

I have the next function in objective c

```
+ (NSString *)getNsLog:(NSString *)pString, ...{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, pString);
    NSLogv(pString, args);
    va_end(args);

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:pString arguments:args]; 
}
```

how can I call this function from swift or convert the code to swift such that when I call the function can be:

```
getNslog("my value1 =  %@ value2 = %@","hello","world")
```

Note that the second param not have alias how this.

```
getNslog("my value1 =  %@ value2 = %@", args:"hello","world")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you call an Objective-C variadic method from Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195796/how-do-you-call-an-objective-c-variadic-method-from-swift). – Summary: You *cannot* call a function with a variable argument list from Swift, only functions taking a `va_list` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved follow:

in objective c change my code to this:

```
+(NSString*)getNsLog:(NSString*)pString args:(va_list)args{

NSLogv(pString, args);

va_end(args);

return [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:pString arguments:args];
}
```

in swift app delegate I add

```
extension MyClass {
class func getNsLog(format: String, _ args: CVarArgType...) -> NSString?
    {
    return MyClass.getNsLog(format, args:getVaList(args))
    }
}
```

now I can call the function

```
NSLog("%@", MyClass.getNsLog("%@,%@", "hello","World")!)
```

I based in the post duplicated [How do you call an Objective-C variadic method from Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195796/how-do-you-call-an-objective-c-variadic-method-from-swift)

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

1. Simply import your class containing this method in `YourProjectname-Bridging-Header.h` file.

   ```
    #import "`YourClass.h"
   ```
2. Create imported class's object

   ```
    var a = YourClass()
   ```
3. then simply call the method and pass required parameter

   ```
   a.getNsLog(yourParameters)
   ```

I hope this helps

Comment: I make it but only this function not is recognized