# Calling Objective-C initializer with variadic arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, initializer, variadic

I'm trying to re-use an Objective-C class, namely [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView), into a Swift project. The problem is that the class uses an initializer with variadic arguments. I followed the same approach suggested at this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195796/how-do-you-call-an-objective-c-variadic-method-from-swift) and my code works in the iOS Simulator if I use the iPad Air but NOT if I use the iPad Retina. The code also crashes on a real iPad 3.

I was able to create a toy example that shows the same issue.

**TestClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestClass : NSObject

@property NSArray *titles;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title otherButtonTitlesVA:(va_list)args;

@end
```

**TestClass.m**

```
#import "TestClass.h"

@implementation TestClass

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title otherButtonTitlesVA:(va_list)args {

    NSMutableArray *titles = [NSMutableArray array];

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        [titles addObject:title];

        id arg;
        if ((arg = va_arg(args, id)) && [arg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { // this causes an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iPad Retina
            [titles addObject:(NSString*)arg];

            while ( nil != ( arg = va_arg( args, id ) ) ) 
            {
                if ( ![arg isKindOfClass: [NSString class] ] )
                    return nil;

                [titles addObject:(NSString*)arg];
            }
        }
    }
    self.titles = [NSArray arrayWithArray:titles];
    return self;
}

@end
```

**TestClass+Swift.swift**

```
import Foundation

extension TestClass {
    convenience init(title:String?, otherButtonTitles:CVarArgType...)
    {
        self.init(title: title, otherButtonTitlesVA:getVaList(otherButtonTitles))
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let testObject1 = TestClass(title: "First", otherButtonTitles: "Second", "Third")
        let testObject2 = TestClass(title: "First") // this causes the initializer to crash on iPad Retina

        NSLog("%@", testObject1.titles)
        NSLog("%@", testObject2.titles)
    }
}
```

The code crashes when trying to create `testObject2` with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Is there anything wrong with my code? Why does the iPad Air show a different behavior from the iPad Retina?

EDIT: OK, I think the problem is that the Objective-C code expects a `nil` terminated list. How do I pass a `nil` terminated `va_list` from Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already figured out, the Objective-C code expects a `nil`
terminated list. Without that, the behavior of

```
if ((arg = va_arg(args, id)) && [arg isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { ... }
```

is undefined if the list of actually passed arguments is exhausted.

`nil` is a NULL pointer in Objective-C, and you can append that in your convenience initializer:

```
extension TestClass {
    convenience init(title:String?, otherButtonTitles : CVarArgType...)
    {
        let nullPtr = UnsafePointer<Void>()
        let otherTitles : [CVarArgType] = otherButtonTitles + [nullPtr]
        self.init(title: title, otherButtonTitlesVA: getVaList(otherTitles))
    }
}
```

This seems to work correctly on both 32- and 64-bit platforms.

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
extension TestClass {
    convenience init(title:String?, otherButtonTitles : CVarArg...)
    {
        let otherTitles : [CVarArg] = otherButtonTitles + [Int(0)]
        self.init(title: title, otherButtonTitlesVA: getVaList(otherTitles))
    }
}
```

As mentioned in https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5046, using an `Int` sized zero is the recommended way to pass a null pointer on a
variable argument list.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the `UnsafePointer<Void>()`! I hadn't thought about that!

Comment: Noticed your recent edit here, and it prompted me to play around with nicer ways of getting a null pointer. This seems to work: `OpaquePointer(nil as UnsafePointer?)`

Comment: Never mind, that returns `Optional<OpaquePointer>.none`... too bad this is so awkward :/

Comment: @jtbandes: Yes,  and  `OpaquePointer?`  does not conform to `CVarArg`. Same with `OpaquePointer(bitPattern: 0)`.